Equation and Function Graphing differences
Why does $(x - a)^2  + y$ not work in desmos graph?
Here $y$ value is $(x - a)^2 + y$
So $(x - a)^2 = 0$
$x-a = 0$
$x =  \pm a$
So graph should shoot up at values of $a$ and $-a$
same like how it would shoot up at $2$ and $-2$ when it is given $x^2 = 4$
Why does it not do that here?

Please improve the formatting of your question. $(x-a)^2 + y$ places no constraints on the relationship between $(x,y)$, and would not be plotted on desmos.

How do you conclude that $(x-a)^2=0$ from that expression? There is no predicate in that expression so there is no concept of a solution.

Are trying to graph (in two dimensions) all satisfying values of $~(x,y)~$ such that $~y = (x-a)^2 + y~?$
